# How to do role permission checking for slash commands in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to check the permissions of the member who executed the slash command, but my code does not work. As I understand it, in April 2022 the rights of bots were updated and now the old method does not work. Here is my code:

```
execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")){
            interaction.reply({ content: "Pong!" });
        } else {
            interaction.reply({ content: "No" });
        }
    }
```

Instead of sending "No" the bot continues to execute the code

Answer (score 1):

As per `Discord.js v14`

```js
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');

execute(interaction) {
    if (interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)){
        interaction.reply({ content: "Pong!" });
    } else {
        interaction.reply({ content: "No" });
    }
}
```

Check out the [docs page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#creating-a-role-with-permissions)

---

[image]

Is the extra inverted comma next to "pong" a copy paste error?

```js
//should be
description: `Sends "Pong"`, //using backticks instead of inverted commas
```

Comment: Is there a way for discord.js v13?

Comment: I haven't fully mastered javascript, can you tell me exactly where to type this?

Comment: i tried to output it to the console but got nothing

Comment: Could I see your full code? Put it in a paste bin or something - remember to obscure your client secret.

Comment: I am using a command handler, all commands are in separate files. https://pastebin.com/spaTWB7n

Comment: Has the handler ever worked for you? If not, its no error with the code - its an error with the handler. I'd recommend you get rid of the handler until you have a good understanding of JavaScript and NodeJS. Try it in just your index.js file for now

Comment: The handler is working, the commands are being executed

Comment: So if you do a simple `console.log('test')` in your `execute` statement and nothing else does it log it? Also, please see my edit - it may solve your problem.

Comment: My command handler is broken and prints output from regular commands. I know what the problem is and will fix it soon

Comment: Make sure you test my solution. It will be causing an error.